# compute stats in impala using impyla

Tags: python, hive, impala, impyla

I'm trying to compute statistics in impala(hive) using python impyla module.

command used:
compute stats db.tablename;

But im getting below error.
**cannot recognize input near 'compute' 'stats'**

How this can be fixed?

Comment: can you pls stare codes? if you are firing `compute stats tabname` in impala, it should work.

Comment: Need to call that from python script using impyla module..

Comment: Followed as it is in below link..https://saagie.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007823519-Read-Write-from-Impala